# how do you monitor your response times using grafana which are hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization, monitoring, grafana

i have couple of APIs hosted on AWS and we have Load balancer and traffic is routed based on listerners rule to TG how do you monitor HTTP 5XX, 4XX and response time on APIs using Grafana

load balancers requests are logged to s3 and s3 has all details of calls made how can we visualize via grafana like API response time, 5XX Count, 4XX Count etc ..

Comment: Not sure if it matches your specific needs behind that but the easiest way is to use Cloudwatch as a source for your Grafana.

Comment: i want path/url level metrics at Grafana which are present is s3

Comment: Then you need Loki to ingest logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing Grafana setup, then please refer [Visualize AWS ELB Application Load Balancer metrics](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/650) document from Grafana.

Else if, you do not have Grafana setup, then using [Amazon Managed Service for Grafana](https://aws.amazon.com/grafana/#) can be an option, which will provide required dashboard with ease.

Comment: i have these metrics already but this does not track at TG/api  level
i want to track at url/path level via Grafana